# GetFiles example throwing exception

Tags: api, office365, getfiles

Using the new Office 365 Tools API I get: "The property 'Puid' does not exist on type 'Microsoft.Office365.SharePoint.UserInformation'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type." when enumerating the returned contents of the GetMyFiles example code. (MyFilesApiSample.cs)

Answer (score 0):

The Files service just introduced a new property that the libraries do not handle. Adding "myFilesClient.Context.IgnoreMissingProperties = true;" to your code should take care of the issue.